# How to write custom functions that Entity Framework can evaluate server side

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Entity Framework (in my case EF 6) can evaluate quite complex queries on the server side.

For instance, the following query gets fully executed as SQL on the database server:

```
var resultModels = _context.Set<MyEntity>()
   .Select(myEntity => new ResultModel() {
      RelaltionPresent = myEntity.Relation1.Any() || (myEntity.Relation2.Any()
    })
   .ToList()
```

This works without even including Relation1 and Relation2. In the query it will include subselects.

However as soon as I create a helper function that doesn't directly contain the logic in the lambda this does not work anymore, for instance:

```
var resultModels = _context.Set<MyEntity>()
   .Select(myEntity => new ResultModel() {
      RelaltionPresent = hasRelations(myEntity)
    })
   .ToList()
```

with a helper function

```
public bool hasRelations(MyEntity myEntity){
    return  myEntity.Relation1.Any() || (myEntity.Relation2.Any();
}
```

This will only work properly when the relations are actually included (as the hasRelations function is executed client side).

How when these mappings in the Select clause happen more often I would like to reuse code rather than copy paste the logic. This does work when I create an extension for `IQueryable` that does the full select, but not on smaller parts of the logic. Is there any way to tell Entity Framework to look into my helper methods when deciding what to run server / client side? Or any alternative to reuse code?

Comment: You can't and shouldn't try. An ORM's job is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows, not act as embedded SQL. It can't do things that aren't possible in SQL nor should it. Trying to force it typically results in *slow*, not complex queries. SQL databases are fast because they can use indexes and statistics to process only the necessary data. What's the execution plan of the LINQ query you posted look like? Does it use indexes, or is it taking a long time to return anything?

Comment: You can simplify LINQ queries up to a point by using the *correct* types. LINQ uses `Expression<Func<...>>`, not plain functions. Your `Select` is using an `Expression<Func<MyEntity,ResultModel>>` which it translates into SQL.  `myEntity.Relation1.Any() || (myEntity.Relation2.Any()` in this case is an expression too, not a function. You can assign it to a variable, eg `Expression<Func<MyEntity,bool>> map=myEntity=>myEntity.Relation1.Any() || myEntity.Relation2.Any();`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not trying to trick the performance, just to reuse code while getting the same SQL. I will give the Expression approach a try.

Comment: Splitting the query will make it even harder to understand what's going on. Why do you even need that `Any()`? Why not just check if `Relation1Id == null || Relation2Id == null` ? If the tables have proper foreign keys, the only way for `.Any()` to return `false` is if `Relation1ID` is null. If they don't, the database has dirty data and a design bug